# Accessing Style of Ionic 2 DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2

I'm trying to access the DOM elements of one of my pages with the following:

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      let elm = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector("ion-navbar.toolbar.toolbar-ios.statusbar-padding");
      console.log(elm.style);
    })
 }
```

However, it appears this element has no style - I have tried various combinations to access it but no luck.

Specifically, I'm looking for the height of the ion-navbar. Is this possible?

Comment: Where do you place this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the actual height of an element with `element.offsetHeight`.

As for the style property, it will give you only the attributes defined in the element's inline style attribute (e.g. `<div style="height: 20px;">...</div>`), not the ones applied by the CSS using selector rules. See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround for that.

```
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.show-tabbar');
      if (tabs !== null) {
          Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
              tabs[key].style.transform = 'translateY(56px)';
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I always have found it terribly useful to simply use
`ionic serve`
inspect the element in chrome and easily see the style for the given device.

To access the DOM element in angular I have used the #id route. The following snippet was used to verify the appropriate class was applied by ionic.

html- home.html

```
<ion-spinner #testspinner name="crescent" paused="{{isPaused}}"></ion-spinner>
```

ts- home.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  isPaused: boolean;
  @ViewChild('testspinner') testspinner;

  constructor() {
    this.isPaused = false; // set to true will cause to never have animation state running.
  }


  containsPausedClass(list: string[]) {
    return (list.indexOf('spinner-paused') != -1);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // if the spinner is allows to load without 'spinner-paused' then safari will work.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isPaused = true;
    }, 0);
    console.log('test spinner is paused ',
      this.containsPausedClass(this.testspinner._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.value));

  }

  togglePause() {
    this.isPaused = !this.isPaused;

    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log('test spinner is paused ',
        this.containsPausedClass(this.testspinner._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.value));
    }, 100);
  }

}
```

Comment: Well aware of that, but the question was about accessing said style from the JS - not a fan of hard coding where it can be avoided.

Comment: Ahh, I think I have done that before.  Let me update my answer. can you use #id?